# How to highlight search results in React-Native FlatList?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, searchbar

I'm newbie in React-native. I need to highlight the search results in my FlatList while I'm typing in search bar. There are 2 componenrs: [react-native-highlight-words](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-highlight-words) and [react-native-text-highlight](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-text-highlight) , But I cant figure out how to make use of them!
here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { List, ListItem, SearchBar } from 'react-native-elements';
import DropdownMenu from 'react-native-dropdown-menu';
import {Header, Left, Right, Icon} from 'native-base'

var SQLite = require('react-native-sqlite-storage')
var db = SQLite.openDatabase({name: 'test.sqlite', createFromLocation: '~dictionary.sqlite'})
var data = [["English", "Arabic", "Persian"]];

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {record: [], arrayholder : [], query:''};
    db.transaction((tx) => {
      tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM tblWord', [], (tx, results) => {
          let row = results.rows.item();
          arrayholder = results.rows.raw()
          record = results.rows.raw()
          this.setState({arrayholder: arrayholder})
          this.setState({ record: record })
          }});});  
      }

  searchFilterFunction = text => {
    var newData = this.state.arrayholder;
    newData = this.state.arrayholder.filter(item => {
      const itemData = item.word_english.toLowerCase()
      const textData = text.toLowerCase()
      return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1 });
    this.setState({query: text,record: newData });
  };


  render() {
    return (
      <View style = {styles.container}>
        <Header style={styles.headerStyle}>
            ...
        </Header>
        <View style={styles.menuView}>
          <DropdownMenu
            bgColor={"#B38687"}
            activityTintColor={'green'}
            titleStyle={{color: '#333333'}} 
            handler={(selection, row) => this.setState({text4: data[selection][row]})}
            data={data}
            >
          </DropdownMenu>
        </View >
        <View >
          <View style={styles.searchBarView}>
            <SearchBar
              placeholder="Search"
              lightTheme
              value = {this.state.query}
              onChangeText={text => this.searchFilterFunction(text)}
              autoCorrect={false}
              inputStyle={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}
              containerStyle={{backgroundColor: 'white', borderWidth: 1, borderColor:'#B38687', }}
              />
          </View>

          <View style={styles.flatListVew}>
            <List containerStyle={{ flexDirection: 'column-reverse', borderTopWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth: 0 }} >
              <FlatList 
                data={this.state.record} 
                keyExtractor={((item, index) => "itemNo-" + index)}
                renderItem={({item}) => (
                  <ListItem
                    roundAvatar
                    onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen2', {data: (item.word_english +'\n' + item.word_arabic)} ); }}
                    title={item.word_english}
                    containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }}
                  /> )}
                />
              </List>
            </View>
          </View>
       </View>);}
          }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 ...
```

I want the results to look like this:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @simaAttar- share code of `ListItem` component.

Comment: @Rocky I edited my question and included my whole code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass text or custom view to [`ListItem`](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/listitem.html) component as `props` for [title](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/listitem.html#title). I am using [React Native Highlight Words](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-highlight-words) to highlight text as you stated.

add `React Native Highlight Words` by add the below line:

```
import Highlighter from 'react-native-highlight-words';
```

Update code for `ListItem` component for desired result:

```
<ListItem
    roundAvatar
    onPress={() => {this.props.navigation.navigate('Screen2', {data: (item.word_english +'\n' + item.word_arabic)} ); }}
    title={
      <Highlighter
          highlightStyle={{backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}
          searchWords={[this.state.query]}
          textToHighlight={item.word_english}
      />}
    containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can highlight using your own styles.

Here is a simple example:

```
const myList = [{ text: 'Hi', id: 1 }, ... ]

class List extends Component {
  this.state = { highlightedId: undefined }

  render() {
    return (
        <FlatList
        data={myList}
        renderItem={({item}) => <Text style={item.id === this.state.highlightedId ? styles.hightlighted : undefined}>{item.text}</Text>}
      />
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  highlighted: {
    backgroundColor: "yellow"
  }
})
```

In your case you can adjust the `containerStyle` of the `<ListItem />`.

Comment: @simaAttar Let me know if you can't do it and I can help you more.

Comment: Actually I dont understand how to implement your code on mine, FYI this is a dictionary app which is going to search for words in the flatList, so if you still believe that your code is suitable, please kindly explain more. Thanks alooot

Comment: I can't see enough code for that. Also the code is formatted in a way that makes it hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
 handleChangeText = param => {
const {categoryList} = this.state;
const regEx = "\\s*(" + param + ")\\s*"
const validator = new RegExp(regEx, 'i');
let filterData = [];
//here is categorylist is the data supplied to flatlist.
categoryList.forEach(item => {
  let flag = validator.test(item.teamtype);
  if (flag) {
    //here set the highlighting color
  }
})
```

};

**Call the above function onChangeText() of your search field.**

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { moderateScale } from 'react-native-size-matters';
import HighlightText from './src/components/HighlightText';
import theme from './src/constants/theme';


    const App = () => {
      return (
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            backgroundColor: theme.whiteColor,
            paddingHorizontal:moderateScale(40)
          }}>
          <HighlightText searchText={"you"} text={"Sometimes in life, life can throw unexpected surprises at you. You might find yourself wondering if you're really making progress, progress that leads you to your dreams. Dreams can be elusive, but they're what keep you going, going forward even when you face obstacles. Obstacles may seem insurmountable, but you have the strength, strength deep within you, to overcome them. So, remember to stay true to yourself, yourself, and keep pursuing your dreams with passion and determination."}  />
        </View>
      );
    };
    export default App;
```

**The highlight component is here .**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';
import fonts from '../constants/fonts';
import { moderateScale } from '../constants/scaling';
import theme from '../constants/theme';
const HighlightText = ({searchText, text}) => {
  //const escapedSearchText = searchText.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&')
  const regex = new RegExp(`(${searchText})`, 'gi');
  const parts = text.split(regex);
  
  return (
    <Text>
      {parts.map((part, i) => {
        console.log('====================================');
        console.log(part.toLowerCase() == searchText.toLowerCase());
        console.log('====================================');
        return (
          <Text
            key={i}
            style={
              part.toLowerCase() == searchText.toLowerCase()
                ? {
                    fontSize: moderateScale(14),
                    fontFamily: fonts.Bold,
                    color: theme.primaryColor,
                    includeFontPadding: false,
                  }
                : {
                    color: theme.textColor,
                    fontSize: moderateScale(14),
                    includeFontPadding: false,
                    fontFamily: fonts.Bold,
                  }
            }>
            {part}
          </Text>
        );
      })}
    </Text>
  );
};

export default HighlightText;
```